# My variable data is null but why it is getting undefine

Tags: angular

this is my model

```
export class HubxDataItemSpModel {

    clinicianHubXSign : string;
   
}
```

and this is how i declare my model in my component

```
export class UserPatientsReportFormComponent implements OnInit {
hubxDataItemSpList : Array<HubxDataItemSpModel>=[];
}
```

and this how i tried to check the data and it shows clinicianHubXSign  is undefined

```
if(this.hubxDataItemSpList[0].clinicianHubXSign === null){
      this.dialogService.confirm('xyz');
    }
```

at the database clinicianHubXSign is null

Comment: For `JavaScript`, Undefined and null aren't the same.
to prevent this issue you can use Optional to prevent this by use `?` and 
 it will look like this `if(this.hubxDataItemSpList[0]?.clinicianHubXSign === null){}`

Comment: i want to check if it is null actually the variable im checking is null.Instead of undefine i want to check if its is null